# Manually separating protocol header from body

Tags: c, http, http-headers

I'm trying to handcraft a HTTP request. My question is, how is the protocol header supposed to be separated from the body? Is there a special byte used or should `\r\n` be adequate?

Thanks

Comment: Did you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You separate the header from the body by a double crlf.

Example from Wikipedia:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 23 May 2005 22:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.3.7 (Unix) (Red-Hat/Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 08 Jan 2003 23:11:55 GMT
ETag: "3f80f-1b6-3e1cb03b"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 138
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close

<html>
<head>
  <title>An Example Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.
</body>
</html>
```